# How can I get the right data from database with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs, react-redux

I made a page by using nodejs+react+redux.
I made a edit button in the page and want to edit my data.

Now I select KUMAMOTO-CTI and change the priority from 5 to 10.I use ajax to get data from database to fill the blank.Before I submit it I can get the right data from database.But when I change priority and click to edit it again.The filled data will be wrong.I have to refresh it to get the right data.

And sometimes it will become like this:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O90j.png)

Could anybody tell me how to solve it?

Here is the pic:[progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDRD8.png)

Here is my code.

server.js

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('koa-router')
const cors = require('koa2-cors')
const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import serversReducer from '../client/reducers/reducer'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

const store = createStore(serversReducer)

const views = require('koa-views')
const co = require('co')
const convert = require('koa-convert')
const json = require('koa-json')
const onerror = require('koa-onerror')
const bodyparser = require('koa-bodyparser')
const logger = require('koa-logger')
const debug = require('debug')('koa2:server')
const path = require('path')
//const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server')
const React = require('react')
const config = require('./config')
const routes = require('./routes')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const stateSchema = require('./models/State')
const mission = require('./models/port')
const port = process.env.PORT || config.port

import Main from '../client/containers/Main'

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/monitor', {
    useMongoClient: true
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var State = mongoose.model("State", stateSchema);

// error handler
onerror(app)
// middlewares
app.use(bodyparser())
    .use(json())
    .use(logger())
    .use(cors())
    .use(require('koa-static')(__dirname + '/public'))
    .use(views(path.join(__dirname, '/views'), {
        options: {
            settings: {
                views: path.join(__dirname, 'views')
            }
        },
        map: {
            'ejs': 'ejs'
        },
        extension: 'ejs'
    }))
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods())

// logger
app.use(async(ctx, next) => {
    const start = new Date()
    await next()
    const ms = new Date() - start
    console.log(`${ctx.method} ${ctx.url} - $ms`)
})

router.get('/', async(ctx, next) => {

    const staticMarkup = await renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Main />
        </Provider>
    )

    const preloadedState = store.getState();
    //console.log(preloadedState);

    await ctx.render('index', {
        reduxData: preloadedState,
        helloComponentMarkup: staticMarkup
    })
})

router.post('/show', async(ctx, next) => {

    ctx.body = 'ok';
    let newArray = [];

    await State.find({}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
        doc.forEach(function(element, index) {
            newArray.push(element);
        })
        ctx.response.body = JSON.stringify(newArray);
    }).sort({
        priority: 1
    })
})

router.post('/edit', async(ctx, next) => {

    ctx.body = 'ok'

    await State.update({
        _id: ctx.request.body.querymark
    }, {
        $set: {
            server_name: ctx.request.body.servername,
            jp_name: ctx.request.body.jpname,
            ip_address: ctx.request.body.ipaddress,
            port: ctx.request.body.port,
            priority: ctx.request.body.priority
        }
    }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
    })
})

router.post('/create', async(ctx, next) => {

    ctx.body = 'ok'

    await new State({
        server_name: ctx.request.body.servername,
        jp_name: ctx.request.body.jpname,
        ip_address: ctx.request.body.ipaddress,
        port: ctx.request.body.port,
        priority: ctx.request.body.priority
    }).save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err.toString());
    })
})

router.post('/delete', async(ctx, next) => {

    ctx.body = 'ok'

    await State.remove({
        _id: ctx.request.body.id
    }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
    });
})

routes(router)

app.on('error', function(err, ctx) {
    console.log(err)
    logger.error('server error', err, ctx)
})

module.exports = app.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${config.port}`)
    console.log(__dirname);
})
```

ListContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { Segment, Icon, Table, Modal, Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
const axios = require('axios')
class ListContainer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        test_data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        post_data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        onDeleteServer: PropTypes.func,
        onEditServer: PropTypes.func,
        initServers: PropTypes.func,
        index: PropTypes.number
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = ({
            servername: props.post_data.server_name,
            jpname: props.post_data.jp_name,
            ipaddress: props.post_data.ip_address,
            port: props.post_data.port,
            priority: props.post_data.priority
        })
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        servers: []
    }

    handleDeleteServer(index) {
        if (this.props.onDeleteServer) {
            this.props.onDeleteServer(this.props.index)
        } else {
            console.log("error")
        }
    }

    /*handleEditServer(index) {
        if (this.props.onEditServer) {
            this.props.onEditServer(this.props.index)
        } else {
            console.log("error")
        }
        this.setState({
            open: false
        })
    }*/

    handleServerNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            servername: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleJPNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            jpname: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleIPChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            ipaddress: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handlePORTChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            port: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handlePriorityChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            priority: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(index) {
        axios.post('/edit', {
            querymark: this.props.post_data._id,
            servername: this.state.servername,
            jpname: this.state.jpname,
            ipaddress: this.state.ipaddress,
            port: this.state.port,
            priority: this.state.priority
        }).then((response) => {
            var new_data;
            if (response.data.success === false) {
                alert("error")
            } else {
                window.location.reload();
                //console.log(this.props.post_data)
                dispatch(onEditServer(index, {
                    querymark: this.props.post_data._id,
                    servername: this.state.servername,
                    jpname: this.state.jpname,
                    ipaddress: this.state.ipaddress,
                    port: this.state.port,
                    priority: this.state.priority
                }))
            }
        }).catch(() => {
        })
        this.setState({
            open: false
        })
    }

    state = {
        open: false
    }

    show = (size, dimmer) => () => this.setState({
        size,
        dimmer,
        open: true
    })
    close = () => this.setState({
        open: false
    })

    render() {
        const {open, size, dimmer} = this.state
        const post_data = this.props.post_data
        var updated_time = (new Date(post_data.updated_at)).toLocaleString().replace('/T/', '').replace('/\../+', '')
        var state_color = (post_data.state == "green") ? "green" : "red"
        var icon_name = (post_data.state == "green") ? "smile" : "warning sign"
        return (
            <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell><Icon name={icon_name} color={state_color}/></Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{post_data.jp_name}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{post_data.ip_address}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{post_data.port}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{updated_time}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{post_data.priority}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                    <div>
                        <Icon link name='settings' color='purple' onClick={this.show('small', 'blurring')} />
                        <Modal size={size} dimmer={dimmer} open={open} onClose={this.close} closeIcon>
                        <Modal.Header>Edit</Modal.Header>             
                        <Modal.Content>
                            <Modal.Description>
                                <Form>
                                <Form.Group width='equal'>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>Server Name</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.servername} onChange={this.handleServerNameChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>JP Name</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.jpname} onChange={this.handleJPNameChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group width='equal'>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>IP Address</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.ipaddress} onChange={this.handleIPChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>Priority</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.priority} onChange={this.handlePriorityChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>Port</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.port} onChange={this.handlePORTChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                            </Modal.Description>
                        </Modal.Content>
                        <Modal.Actions>
                        <Button color='black' onClick={this.close}>
                            Nope
                        </Button>
                        <Button positive icon='checkmark' labelPosition='right' content="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} />
                        </Modal.Actions>
                        </Modal>
                    </div>
                </Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell><Icon link name='trash' color='purple' onClick={this.handleDeleteServer.bind(this)} /></Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        servers: state.servers
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onEditServer: (index, data) => {
            dispatch(editServer(index, data))
        },
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ListContainer)
```

SegmentContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Container, Loader, Table, Grid, Icon, Button, Modal, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import SegmentList from '../components/SegmentContainer'
import { initServers, deleteServer, editServer } from '../reducers/reducer'
import MenuFix from '../components/Menu'
const axios = require('axios')

class SegmentContainer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        servers: PropTypes.array,
        initServers: PropTypes.func,
        onDeleteServer: PropTypes.func,
        onAddServer: PropTypes.func
    }

    constructor() {
        super()
        //this._loadData()
        this.state = {
            servername: '',
            jpname: '',
            ipaddress: '',
            priority: ''
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this._loadData()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.timer) {
            clearInterval(this.timer)
        }
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this._loadData()
        }, 3000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer)
    }

    _loadData() {
        let sorted_data = [];
        let posts_data = [];
        let response = axios.post('/show')
            .then((response) => {
                Object.keys(response.data).forEach(function(index) {
                    sorted_data.push(response.data[index]);
                })

                function _dataCompare(a, b) {
                    if (a.priority > b.priority)
                        return 1;
                    if (a.priority < b.priority)
                        return -1;
                    return 0;
                }

                sorted_data.forEach((item, index) => {
                    posts_data.push(item);
                })
                posts_data.sort(_dataCompare);
                this.props.initServers(posts_data)
            //dispatch(initServers(posts_data))
            }).catch(() => {
        })

    }

    handleDeleteServer(index) {
        const {servers} = this.props
        axios.post('/delete', {
            id: servers[index]._id
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.success === false) {
                alert("error");
            } else {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }).catch(() => {
        })
        if (this.props.onDeleteServer) {
            this.props.onDeleteServer(index)
        }
    }

    /*handleEditServer(index) {
        const {servers} = this.props
        axios.post('/edit', {
            querymark: this.props.servers._id,
            servername: this.state.servername,
            jpname: this.state.jpname,
            ipaddress: this.state.ipaddress,
            port: this.state.port,
            priority: this.state.priority
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.success === false) {
                alert("error")
            } else {
                //window.location.reload();
                dispatch(onEditServer(index, {
                    querymark: this.props.servers._id,
                    servername: this.state.servername,
                    jpname: this.state.jpname,
                    ipaddress: this.state.ipaddress,
                    port: this.state.port,
                    priority: this.state.priority
                }))
            }
        }).catch(() => {
        })
        this.setState({
            open: false
        })
    }*/

    handleCreate(server) {
        axios.post('/create', {
            servername: this.state.servername,
            jpname: this.state.jpname,
            ipaddress: this.state.ipaddress,
            port: this.state.port,
            priority: this.state.priority
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.success === false) {
                alert("error");
            } else {
                window.location.reload()
                dispatch(onAddServer(index, {
                    servername: this.state.servername,
                    jpname: this.state.jpname,
                    ipaddress: this.state.ipaddress,
                    port: this.state.port,
                    priority: this.state.priority
                }))
            }
        }).catch(() => {
        })
        this.setState({
            open: false
        })
    }

    handleServerNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            servername: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleJPNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            jpname: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleIPChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            ipaddress: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handlePORTChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            port: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handlePriorityChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            priority: event.target.value
        })
    }

    state = {
        open: false
    }
    show = (size, dimmer) => () => this.setState({
        size,
        dimmer,
        open: true
    })

    close = () => this.setState({
        open: false
    })

    render() {
        const {open, size, dimmer} = this.state
        return (
            <Grid>
            <MenuFix /> 
            <Container style = {{
                marginTop: '6em'
            }}>
                <Table unstackable>
                    <Table.Header>
                        <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='8'>
                            <Button basic color='violet' floated='right' icon labelPosition='left' primary size='tiny' onClick={this.show('small', 'blurring')}>
                                <Icon link color='violet' name='add' />Add
                            </Button>
                            <Modal size={size} dimmer={dimmer} open={open} onClose={this.close} closeIcon>
                            <Modal.Header>Add</Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Content>
                                <Modal.Description>
                                    <Form>
                                <Form.Group width='equal'>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>Server Name</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.servername} onChange={this.handleServerNameChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>JP Name</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.jpname} onChange={this.handleJPNameChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group width='equal'>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>IP Address</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.ipaddress} onChange={this.handleIPChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>Priority</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.priority} onChange={this.handlePriorityChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>Port</label>
                                    <input value={this.state.port} onChange={this.handlePORTChange.bind(this)} />
                                </Form.Field>
                                </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                                </Modal.Description>
                            </Modal.Content>
                            <Modal.Actions>
                                <Button color='black' onClick={this.close}>
                                    Nope
                                </Button>
                                <Button positive icon='checkmark' labelPosition='right' content="Submit" onClick={this.handleCreate.bind(this)} />
                            </Modal.Actions>
                            </Modal>
                        </Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                        <Table.Row>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>State<Loader active inline size='small' /></Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Server Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>IP Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Port</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Updated</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Priority</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Edit</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Delete</Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                    </Table.Header>
                    <SegmentList posts_data = {this.props.servers} onDeleteServer={this.handleDeleteServer.bind(this)} />
                </Table>
            </Container>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        servers: state.servers
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        initServers: (servers) => {
            dispatch(initServers(servers))
        },
        onDeleteServer: (index) => {
            dispatch(deleteServer(index))
        },
        onEditServer: (index, data) => {
            dispatch(editServer(index, data))
        },
        onAddServer: (server) => {
            dispatch(addServer(server))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SegmentContainer)
```

reducer.js

```
//action types
const INIT_SERVERS = 'INIT_SERVERS'
const ADD_SERVER = 'ADD_SERVER'
const DELETE_SERVER = 'DELETE_SERVER'
const EDIT_SERVER = 'EDIT_SERVER'

//reducer

export default function(state, action) {
    if (!state) {
        state = {
            servers: []
        }
    }
    switch (action.type) {
    case INIT_SERVERS:
        return {
            servers: action.servers
        }
    case ADD_SERVER:
        return {
            servers: [...state.servers, action.server]
        }
    case EDIT_SERVER:
        return {
            servers: [...state.servers.slice(0, action.index), Object.assign({}, state.servers[action.index], {
                done: true
            }), ...state.servers.slice(action.index + 1)]
        /*servers: Object.assign([...state.servers], {
            [index]: action.data
        })*/
        //servers: Object.assign({}, state[action.index], action.data)
        }
    case DELETE_SERVER:
        return {
            servers: [
                ...state.servers.slice(0, action.index),
                ...state.servers.slice(action.index + 1)
            ]
        }
    default:
        return state
    }
}

// action creators
export const initServers = (servers) => {
    return {
        type: INIT_SERVERS,
        servers
    }
}

export const addServer = (server) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_SERVER,
        server
    }
}

export const deleteServer = (index) => {
    return {
        type: DELETE_SERVER,
        index
    }
}

export const editServer = (index, data) => {
    return {
        type: EDIT_SERVER,
        index,
        data
    }
}
```

SegmentList.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import ListContainer from '../containers/ListContainer'


export default class SegmentList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        posts_data: PropTypes.array,
        onDeleteServer: PropTypes.func,
    //onEditServer: PropTypes.func
    }
    static defaultProps = {
        posts_data: []
    }

    handleDeleteServer(index) {
        if (this.props.onDeleteServer) {
            this.props.onDeleteServer(index)
        }
    }

    /*handleEditServer(index) {
        if (this.props.onEditServer) {
            this.props.onEditServer(index)
        }
    }*/

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.posts_data.map((data, i) => <ListContainer
                post_data={data}
                key={i}
                index={i} onDeleteServer={this.handleDeleteServer.bind(this)} />
            )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, react is for SPA, if you use reload just use HTTP (no ajax) to edit.  Here is solution for SPA

before coding, the main idea is to update your data after edit, so the road map should be:

1.fetch an array from server and store into `state.servers`, and it should be a list of plain objects that contain your server info

2.when you update, you should apply the update to server and then update to local store, as you did in create/delete, edit is most likely the same thing with more data

then your `handleSubmit` should be (notice index from iteration as param)

```js
//index from iteration, should be passed from parent component

handleSubmit(index) {
  const data = {
    querymark: this.props.post_data._id,
    servername: this.state.servername,
    jpname: this.state.jpname,
    ipaddress: this.state.ipaddress,
    port: this.state.port,
    priority: this.state.priority
  }
  axios.post('/edit', data).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.success === false) {
      alert("error");
    } else {
      //window.location.reload();
      dispatch(onEditServer(index,data))
    }
  }).catch(() => {})
  this.setState({
    open: false
  })
}
```

`onEditServer` should be

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    initServers: (servers) => {
      dispatch(initServers(servers))
    },
    onDeleteServer: (serverIndex) => {
      dispatch(deleteServer(serverIndex))
    },
    onEditServer: (index, data) => {
      dispatch(editServer({
        type: 'edit',
        index,
        data,
      }))
    },
    onAddServer: (server) => {
      dispatch(addServer(server))
    }
  }
}
```

edit reducer

```js
// edit reducer
const edit = (state, action) {
  state.servers[action.index] = actions.data
  return state
}
```

then changes will take effect automatically

Comment: Thank you.According to your comment, I edit my code but it still have the same problem.I edit my question.Could you tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: @RunChicken `onEditServer `, `data` inside  `dispatch(onEditServer(index, data))` is not assigned, isn't it? I will update thoughts behind these codes to my answer

Comment: I can see the change but when I want to edit the same data again,it can not get the right data.

Comment: if you mean others might change the data, then you need a version in your server info and deal it both backend and frontend

Comment: `case EDIT_SERVER:
        return {
            servers: [...state.servers, state.servers[action.index] = action.data]
        }`  this is not assigning data to the right index, if you want it more immutable  `return [...state.slice(0, action.index), 
        Object.assign({}, state[action.index], {done: true}),
        ...state.slice(action.index + 1)]` or just `Object.assign` will work

Comment: `[...arr,item]` means to append item to the end, quick answer `servers:Object.assign([...arr],{[index]:item})`, you can use redux/react dev tool to check if you get it right

Comment: I try what you advised.It dose not work.If I want to get the right data I have to refresh twice.Some wrong with other codes?

Comment: I make it work by using return [...state.slice(0, action.index), Object.assign({}, state[action.index], {done: true}), ...state.slice(action.index + 1)] .But still have to use window.location.reload() to automatically refresh it.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, state[action.index], {done: true})` should be `Object.assign({}, state[action.index], action.data)`

Comment: `dispatch(onEditServer(index, data))` should be `dispatch(onEditServer(index, {
    querymark: this.props.post_data._id,
    servername: this.state.servername,
    jpname: this.state.jpname,
    ipaddress: this.state.ipaddress,
    port: this.state.port,
    priority: this.state.priority
  }))` as I mentioned before

Comment: Thank you for your advice.Unfortunately It still not work.Additionally I sorted the data before it showed by using priority.If I do not sort the data it will be right. I update my question and add SegmentList.js. Which provide the data to ListContianer.js   to render.It is something wrong with it?

Comment: `case EDIT_SERVER: return { servers:()=>{const arr=Object.assign({}, state[action.index], action.data);arr.sort(your_compare_function);return arr }()}` do sort whenever server list changes

Comment: case EDIT_SERVER: return { servers:()=>{const arr=Object.assign({}, state[action.index], action.data);arr.sort(your_compare_function);return arr }()} This will just make the view sorted. But data cursor will not change.I want to change the state in ListContainers render part, but I do not know how to get the right property.

Comment: properties from props are always right, I guess it showed a different server after update priority, to solve this you can keep open flag to your store servers, states inside a low level component will bind with `key`

Comment: key={server.id} will work if your server has an identity field, or you can move states data to according server inside redux store

Comment: I try many times but fail.I upload it to github. Could you help me to check where am I wrong?  Here is address https://github.com/SuperUncleCat/example.git.

Comment: `root@localhost:~/example# npm install

> raw-socket@1.5.1 install /root/example/node_modules/raw-socket
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/root/example/node_modules/raw-socket/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/raw/src/raw.o
../src/raw.cc: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE raw::CreateChecksum(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
` got problems during install, I'll try a minimal one without backend

Comment: I will update a new one. May be you can use the states.json to make a mongodb and change the ipaddress in server.js. By the way I update my question and upload a error pictiure there is a strange problem.

Comment: result http://139.162.98.16:8899/  and code  https://github.com/postor/sorted-list-with-edit/blob/master/tools/store/index.js   https://github.com/postor/sorted-list-with-edit/blob/master/pages/index.js read these two files is enough

Comment: Thank you.I will check my program refer to your code.

Comment: http://139.162.98.16:8899/ I found it down and restarted it. As you can see larger priority is always at the bottom, and open state still bind to the correct item

Comment: I tried to imitate your code but failed.everything is ok except the this.state.xx.It keeps the initial condition and won't change to new state when the priority changed.I don't know how to make this part: const Index = (props) => {
  const { servers = [], dispatch } = props
  return (<ul>
    {servers.map((x, i) => {
      return (<Item key={x.id} {...x} index={i} dispatch={dispatch} />)
    })}
  </ul>
  )
}
export default reduxWrapper(connect(state => state)(Index))
work in my program.I tired to pass key and dispatch to ListContainer.js but fail.I update my program on github.